# Outlining and partially filling an SVG Shape

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/apbuc773/

I'd like to create a star using svg.

I'd like to stroke the outside of the star. In my example the stroke is on every line which dissects the inner shape.

Also is it possible to half fill the star shape.

I'd like to use this for a star rating but I need half and maybe quarter fills.

```
    <svg height="210" width="500">
      <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:red;stroke:blue;"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Rather than defining five vertices in the polygon for each point in the star, you really should define one for each vertex in the actual shape. In this case, there are ten. Define those as well and the shape will be well defined, and the stroke will only apply to the outside.

Comment: OK, I've created the star and the stoke but can I half fill the shape - http://jsfiddle.net/apbuc773/5/

Comment: All I can suggest is maybe a [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) could do what you want?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can alternatively do this with a filter. Here is one that animates the fill:

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <defs>
    <filter id="fillpartial" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feFlood x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="red" />
      <feOffset dy="0.5">
        <animate attributeName="dy" from="1" to=".5" dur="3s" />
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon filter="url(#fillpartial)" points="165.000, 185.000, 188.511, 197.361, 184.021, 171.180,
 203.042, 152.639,
 176.756, 148.820,
 165.000, 125.000,
 153.244, 148.820,
 126.958, 152.639,
 145.979, 171.180,
 141.489, 197.361,
 165.000, 185.000" style="fill:white;stroke:red;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: this is great but can we add any icon like thumb icon and fill it with red or any other color?

Comment: Yes. This works with any shape filled with white and any color - just change the flood-color in the filter to whatever you want. (Remember to also change the stroke color on the shape you're filling to the same color)

Comment: @MichaelMullany is it possible to add `turbulence` and `displacement` to this?

Answer (score 16):

Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/apbuc773/11/

Gradient can be used like this:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="half">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
        </linearGradient>            
    </defs>
    <g fill="url(#half)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2">
```

If you don't want to change your polygon points, just apply this polygon twice: one time with stroke and one time without.

Comment: You can actually omit the first and last stop in your gradient.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed the comment of the accepted answer, and here is how you fill an custom shape:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="heart">
        <path d="M81.495,13.923c-11.368-5.261-26.234-0.311-31.489,11.032C44.74,13.612,29.879,8.657,18.511,13.923  C6.402,19.539,0.613,33.883,10.175,50.804c6.792,12.04,18.826,21.111,39.831,37.379c20.993-16.268,33.033-25.344,39.819-37.379  C99.387,33.883,93.598,19.539,81.495,13.923z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" fill="rgb(217,217,217)" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#heart)" />
  <rect x="0" y="50%" fill="red" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#heart)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is really useful for someone using a <path> vs. <polygon>. Relevant MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath