# How to fill an SVG element half portion by a pattern

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I have some SVG elements on which there are some pattern already applied. The pattern is applied as fill color. That means the pattern fills up whole SVG element. Basically i want to partially fill up my element using the pattern.

**Example**

After applying pattern:

[image]

I want this pattern to apply on bottom half of the circle. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlining and partially filling an SVG Shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368138/outlining-and-partially-filling-an-svg-shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create two **circles** and apply [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) on one with `fill`

```html
<svg width="105px" height="105px">
  <mask x="0" y="0" id="half">
    <rect y="50%" fill="white" width="100%" height="50%" />
  </mask>
  
  <circle fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="3px" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50"/>
  <circle fill="#C04C4C" mask="url(#half)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3px" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thanks for your comment.

But is it possible to do that without duplicating my element?

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```html
<svg  height="300" width="300">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="Gradient-1" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
<stop offset="50%" stop-color= "white" />
<stop offset="51%" stop-color= "red" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="repeat"xlink:href="#Gradient-1" spreadMethod="repeat" />
</defs>
 
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"
      fill= "url(#repeat)"
      stroke="#000000"
      stroke-width="1px" />
</svg>
```

Comment: But there is no patterns involved, any idea how can i integrate a pattern here?