# Is it possible to only show half of a SVG icon?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, react-icons

I currently have a rating system that produces 5 stars that can show half values. I did this by using FontAwesome's Half Stars and did some CSS tricks to make them look like one star. But I was thinking of increasing my React and CSS knowledge by coming up with a way to show only half of an SVG icon. So instead of using the Half Stars, I could use whatever Icon the user wanted, and it would only show 50% of the Icon for example if you wanted to give a 3.5 rating.

Q: Can you show only half of an Icon and somehow know if the user is clicking on one side or the other?

Here is the code I have currently that uses the HalfStars for a little bit of reference

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FaRegStarHalf, FaStarHalf } from 'react-icons/fa'

import './styles/Rater.css'

const Rater = ({ iconCount }) => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null)
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(null)
    // check if user has set a rating by clicking a star and use rating to determine icons
    const Star = rating ? FaStarHalf : FaRegStarHalf

    return (
        <div>
            {[...Array(iconCount), ...Array(iconCount)].map((icon, i) => {
                const value = (i + 1) / 2

                return (
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type='radio'
                            name='rating'
                            value={value}
                            onClick={() => {
                                console.log(`value => `, value)
                                return setRating(value)
                            }}
                        />
                        <div className='star-container'>
                            <div>
                                <Star
                                    className={i % 2 ? 'star-left' : 'star'}
                                    color={value <= (hover || rating) ? '#ffc107' : '#e4e5e9'}
                                    onMouseEnter={() => setHover(value)}
                                    onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Rater
```

Comment: If you want to be able to show half a star, and detect which half was clicked, the easiest way is to show the (half) star as the background image of an `<a>` tag. That means you'll also have to set the width of the tag so only half the SVG shows, so you might have to change the tag's `display` property to `inline-block`.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368138/outlining-and-partially-filling-an-svg-shape/29382938#29382938

Comment: You could use CSS [`clip-path`](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) to mask out the star, then check in the click handler if the coordinate of the click is on the first or second half of the icon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written a code to get you the idea; If you click on the right side of the star, its color changes to blue and if you click on the left side, its color changes to gold. Also, it's better to not use `stopPropagation` and check `e.target` of the event.

```js
const starIcon = document.getElementById("star");
const icon = document.getElementById("icon");
starIcon.onclick = e => {
  starIcon.style.color = "blue";
  e.stopPropagation();
};
icon.onclick = e => {
  starIcon.style.color = "gold";
}
```

```css
i {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 50%);
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
      <span id="icon"><i id="star", class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 5):

**You can do it in ONE SVG**

- I ditched the Font-Awesome icon
- searched for "star" in the 7000+ icons on https://iconmeister.github.io/ (first load takes a minute)
- Picked the star icon with the **best d-path** (Clarity Iconset: `cl-social-star-solid`)
- copied **only the d-path**
- Edited the d-path in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ to a **100x100**
  viewBox/grid
- made it an **inverse** star by prepending `M0 0h100v100h-100v-100` to the path
- Created a new SVG file in a `0 0 300 100` viewBox to fit 3 stars.. see below
- Added a **background rectangle** setting **gold** color rating with `width="50%"`
- Used **3** inverse stars, each at an x-offset
- added **6 rectangles** ***covering*** all half-stars
- set inline events on every "half-star"
  (the click works in this SO snippet, but SO adds a long delay)

#### Proof of Concept

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" width="500px">
  <rect id="rating" width="50%" fill="gold" height="100%" />

  <path id="star" fill="green" 
        d="M0 0h100v100h-100v-100m91 42a6 6 90 00-4-10l-22-1a1 1 90 01-1 
           0l-8-21a6 6 90 00-11 0l-8 21a1 1 90 01-1 1l-22 1a6 6 90 00-4 
           10l18 14a1 1 90 010 1l-6 22a6 6 90 008 6l19-13a1 1 90 011 0l19
           13a6 6 90 006 0a6 6 90 002-6l-6-22a1 1 90 010-1z"/>
    <use href="#star" x="100" />
    <use href="#star" x="200" />

  <rect id="c" width="16.66%" height="100%" fill="transparent" stroke="red" 
        onclick="console.log(this)" />
    <use href="#c" x="50" />
    <use href="#c" x="100" />
    <use href="#c" x="150" />
    <use href="#c" x="200" />
    <use href="#c" x="250" />
</svg>
```

## A Star Rating Component `<star-rating stars=N >`

You don't want to create all this SVG by hand... couple lines of JavaScript can create the SVG, for any number of stars

Using a **W3C standard Web Component** here, because it runs in this page and is not as complex as a React Component.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

- Not using `<use>`, just duplicate all paths and rects with a `x` offset
- mouseover events set the background % color
- click shows the index of the clicked halfstar (0+)
- Rating can be set with values **or** percentage; `document.querySelector('[stars="5"]').rating="90%"`  (4.5 stars)
- **needs extra work for your use case**

#### All required HTML & JavaScript:

```html
<star-rating stars=5 rating="3.5"
             bgcolor="green" nocolor="grey" color="gold"></star-rating>
<star-rating stars=7 rating="50%"
             bgcolor="rebeccapurple" nocolor="beige" color="goldenrod"></star-rating>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => console.log(evt.target.getAttribute("n")))

  customElements.define("star-rating", class extends HTMLElement {
    set rating( rate ) {
      if (!String(rate).includes("%")) rate = Number(rate) / this.stars * 100 + "%";
      this.querySelector("#rating").setAttribute("width", rate);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let { bgcolor, stars, nocolor, color, rating } = this.attributes;
      this.stars = ~~stars.value || 5;
      this.innerHTML = 
        `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${this.stars*100} 100" style="cursor:pointer;width:300px">`
      + `<rect width="100%" height="100" fill="${nocolor.value}"/>`
      + `<rect id="rating"  height="100" fill="${color.value}"  />`
        + Array(  this.stars     ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<path fill="${bgcolor.value}" d="M${ n*100 } 0h102v100h-102v-100m91 42a6 6 90 00-4-10l-22-1a1 1 90 01-1 0l-8-21a6 6 90 00-11 0l-8 21a1 1 90 01-1 1l-22 1a6 6 90 00-4 10l18 14a1 1 90 010 1l-6 22a6 6 90 008 6l19-13a1 1 90 011 0l19 13a6 6 90 006 0a6 6 90 002-6l-6-22a1 1 90 010-1z"/>`)
               .join("")
        + Array(  this.stars * 2 ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<rect x="${ n*50 }" n="${n}" opacity="0" width="50" height="100"`
                  + ` onclick="dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))" `
                  + ` onmouseover="this.closest('star-rating').rating = ${(n+1)/2}"/>`)
              .join("") 
      + "</svg>";

      this.rating = rating.value;
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Notes**:

- This **native** `<star-rating>` Component (also called ***Custom Element*** because NO shadowDOM is involved) has **ZERO dependencies**

  - no libraries
  - no external SVG
- native components are not self-closing tags and must contain a hyphen, so notation is: `<star-rating></star-rating>`
- Changed the star to `M0 0h102v100h-102v-100` (2 pixel overlap) to cover SVG rounding issues

#### Supported in all Frameworks... except...

React doesn't support this modern W3C Web Components **Standard** yet.

React scores just **71%** on https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

All other Frameworks (Angular, Vue, Svelte) have **100%** support

You have to do some extra work to handle native DOM Elements and Events in React; but the Custom Element isn't complex.. it creates SVG; should be easy to replicate as a React Component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different idea using 3D transformation:

```css
i {
  color: gold;
}

.container {
  background: #fff;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.half {
  transform: rotateY(1deg);
}

i.fa-star:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <i id="star" class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
  <i id="star" class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
  <i id="star" class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
  <i id="star" class="fas fa-star fa-5x half"></i>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <i id="star" class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
  <i id="star" class="fas fa-star fa-5x half"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to have a row of the svg icons and then use `overflow:hidden` to clip up to the user's selection.

Then using half the width of the icon, it can go by half increments.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on("mousemove", ".star-container.unvoted", function(e)
    {
        let width = $(this).find(".star").width() / 2;

        e.clientX = Math.ceil(e.clientX /= (width)) * width;

        $(this).find(".inner").css("width", e.clientX + "px");
    });

    $(".star-container.unvoted").click(function(e)
    {
        $(this).removeClass("unvoted");
    }); 
});
```

```css
.star-container .inner{
overflow: hidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.star-container .inner .star{
display:inline-block;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-image:url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/1828/1828884.svg');
background-size:contain;
}

.star-container .inner .inner-2{
width:10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="star-container unvoted">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="inner-2">
                <div class="star"></div><div class="star"></div><div class="star"></div><div class="star"></div><div class="star"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```