# How to partially fill an SVG

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I have an Hour Glass shaped svg inside of a react component. What is the best way to partially fill the hourglass? Is it in the svg code? Or should this be done with CSS (styled-components)?

```
export default function HourGlass({ percent }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Glass
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
      >
        <title>hourglass</title>
        <g data-name="Layer 51">
          <path d="M20,16.168v.152a10.019,10.019,0,0,1,6,9.168v4a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H7a1,1,0,0,1-1-1v-4a10.019,10.019,0,0,1,6-9.168v-.153A10.019,10.019,0,0,1,6,7V3A1,1,0,0,1,7,2H25a1,1,0,0,1,1,1V7A10.021,10.021,0,0,1,20,16.168Z"></path>
        </g>
      </Glass>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Glass = styled.svg`
  width: 4.2em;
  fill: green;
`;
```

Comment: please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368138/outlining-and-partially-filling-an-svg-shape

Comment: That answer doesn't address wether or not this is something that should be done in css... or the best approach to this problem in React, how to translate percentages to the linear gradient. Also, the solution is quite complex because it animates a polygon as opposed to partially filing the svg...